# the shortest path in cycle directed Graph

Tags: path, short

i need an example of the shortest path of directed graph cycle bye one node (it should reach to all nodes of graph from anode will be the input) please if there is an example i need it in c++ or algorithm thanks very much.........

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789159/cycle-directed-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require to find the [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)  for it.

For directed graph according to wikipedia you can use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%E2%80%93Liu/Edmonds_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: Link for the algo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu–Liu/Edmonds_algorithm . I am not able to put the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Pseudocode:

```
//INPUT: graph G = (V,E)
//OUTPUT: shortest cycle length
min_cycle(G)
  min = ∞
  for u in V
    len = dij_cyc(G,u)
    if min > len
      min = len
  return min    

//INPUT: graph G and vertex s
//OUTPUT: minimum distance back to s
dij_cyc(G,s)
  for u in V
    dist(u) = ∞
                   //makequeue returns a priority queue of all V
  H = makequeue(V) //using dist-values as keys with s First In
  while !H.empty?
    u = deletemin(H)
    for all edges (u,v) in E
      if dist(v) > dist(u) + l(u,v) then
        dist(v) = dist(u) + l(u,v)
        decreasekey(H,v)

  return dist(s)
```

This runs a slightly different Dijkstra's on each vertex. The mutated Dijkstras
has a few key differences. First, all initial distances are set to ∞, even the
start vertex. Second, the start vertex must be put on the queue first to make 
sure it comes off first since they all have the same priority. Finally, the
mutated Dijkstras returns the distance back to the start node. If there was no
path back to the start vertex the distance remains ∞. The minimum of all these
returns from the mutated Dijkstras is the shortest path. Since Dijkstras runs
at worst in O(|V|^2) and min_cycle runs this form of Dijkstras |V| times, the
final running time to find the shortest cycle is O(|V|^3). If min_cyc returns
∞ then the graph is acyclic.

To return the actual path of the shortest cycle only slight modifications need to be made.